# R shiny break line in button label

Tags: r, button, shiny, label, line-breaks

Please see the following toy example.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("btnId", "I want a line break here <br/> since the label is too long")),
server = function(input, output){})
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `HTML` function like this:

```
library(shiny)

    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        actionButton("btnId", HTML("I want a line break here <br/> since the label is too long"))),
      server = function(input, output){})
```