# Add line break in checkboxGroupInput choices - Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I want to add a line break in one choice because it is too long. Answers to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882025/r-shiny-break-line-in-button-label/46882196#46882196) about the label of a button say to wrap the string in `HTML()`, but the solution does not seem to work for `choices` in `checkboxGroupInput()`.

## Simple example code

```
library(shiny)

choices_vector <- c(
  'Choice 1',
  HTML('Choice 2 shoulde be<br />on two lines'),
  'Choice 3'
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = 'choices_selec',
    label = '',
    choices = choices_vector
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## Original example code

This is older example code and is more complicated. It is left here because one answer uses many of the specifics of this example.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  splitLayout(cellWidths = c(170,80,160),
              tagList(uiOutput("example")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  choices_vector <- c("choice 1","choice 2",HTML("I want a line break here <br/> since the label is too long"),"choice 4")
  output$example <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "choices_selec",
                       label = "", choices = choices_vector, selected = F)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also tried using using `paste0` and  `collapse` (see the following code) and changing `uiOutput` for `htmlOutput` but the results are the same

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  choices_vector <- c("choice 1","choice 2",paste0(c("I want a line break here ", "since the label is too long"), collapse = "<p/>"),"choice 4")
  output$example <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "choices_selec",
                       label = "", choices = choices_vector, selected = F)
  })
}
```

Comment: I think this example code should be simplified to include only the issue in the question. If the question is not about renderUI or splitLayout, those extra complications should be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `checkboxGroupInput` only accepts strings as `choices`. There is nothing we can do unless you change the Shiny source code. Try to think out of the box, why do we need to do it at R preprocessing level. We can use js to post-process it on the client-side (browser).

Here's how, do as usual, but just add this very simple js code after the checkbox:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  splitLayout(cellWidths = c(170,80,160),
              tagList(uiOutput("example")))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  choices_vector <- c("choice 1"="c1","choice 2"="c2", "I want a line break here<br/> since the label is too long"="c3","choice 4"="c4")
  output$example <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "choices_selec",
                         label = "", choices = choices_vector, selected = F),
      tags$script(
        "
        $('#choices_selec .checkbox label span').map(function(choice){
            this.innerHTML = $(this).text();
        });
        "
      )
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    print(input$choices_selec)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

This code will allow you to use any HTML tag as string input. The HTML will be parsed once the check box is rendered.

I also add names to the choice vector, so you will have a better way on the server side to know what choices are selected.

Comment: Can this answer be made more general? It should not just say how to change the example code in the question (which should also be simplified). Do any parts of the JS code reference objects/names that are specific to the example code? How can a person decide where to put the JS in general? Does this only work with renderUI? I could not get this working in my application.

Answer (score 0):

## choiceNames vs. choices

The documentation for `checkboxGroupInput()` explains:

> The advantage of using [`choiceNames` and `choiceValues`] over a named list for choices is that `choiceNames` allows any type of UI object to be passed through (tag objects, icons, HTML code, ...), instead of just simple text.

In other words, this works:

```
checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = 'InputCorrect',
    label = 'Correct',
    choiceNames = list(
      'Choice 1',
      HTML('Choice 2 is<br />on two lines'),
      'Choice 3'
    ),
    choiceValues = 1:3,
  )
```

but this does not:

```
  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = 'InputIncorrect',
    label = 'Incorrect',
    choices = list(
      'Choice 1',
      HTML('Choice 2 is<br />not on two lines'),
      'Choice 3'
    )
  )
```

## Don’t use vectors

Extra complications to keep in mind when passing a previously-defined list to `choiceNames`:

First, **use `list()` instead of `c()` when defining the `choiceNames`**. Elements of a vector must be the same type. Thus, `c('A', HTML('B'), 'C')` does not actually have any `HTML` elements. Also, I think R does not support vectors of HTML elements, anyway.

Second, when placing the `HTML()` in the list manually is not feasible/desirable, **make a character vector and then use `lapply()` to change every element to `HTML`**:

```
choices_vector = c('Choice 1', 'Choice 2 is<br />not on two lines', 'Choice 3')
choices_vector = lapply(choices_vector, HTML)
```

## Working example

(Note the use of `lapply`)

```
library(shiny)

choices_vector = c(
  'Choice 1',
  'Choice 2 is<br />on two lines',
  'Choice 3'
)

ui = fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(
    inputId = 'InputExistingList',
    label = 'Also correct',
    choiceNames = lapply(choices_vector, HTML),
    choiceValues = 1:length(choices_vector),
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```